# calculating the height and size in one function using recursion?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have this function that will recursively find the height of the binary tree and with each recursive call I will increment the variable (s) which refers to the size,and then it will return the height and size as reference, but i am not quite sure if this is the right way?

```
int help(BinaryNode* root, int h, int s){
      if(root== nullptr)
      return0;
      return 1 + max(help(root->left, h, s++), help(root->right, h, s++));
      }
```

Comment: `s` is unnecessary because you never perform checks on or return its value, and likewise for `h`. All you need is the input node pointer `root`.

Comment: FWIW I would add a `size` member to the BTree and just query that to get the size.  Then you just need to worry about computing the height.

Comment: There are no references in this code. Returning references to `h` and `s` would be a bad idea (those two variables die when you leave the function, the references would be dangling). The first thing you need to figure out is how you want to pass the computed information to the caller. Maybe you want `h` and `s` to be references? Maybe you want to return a `std::pair` or even a custom struct?

Comment: `s++` will increment `s` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to return two values, you could pass them both by reference:

```c
int h, s;
help(root, h, s);
```

Then the function would roughly look like:

```c
void help(BinaryNode* root, int& h, int& s) {
  if (!root) {
    h = s = 0;
  } else {
    int hl, sl, hr, sr; /* left and right data */
    help(root->left, hl, sl);
    help(root->right, hr, sr);
    h = 1 + max(hl, hr);
    s = 1 + sl + sr;
  }
}
```

Comment: If we're in C++, passing by reference is much better. That would look something like this: `void help(BinaryNode* root, int& h, int& s)`